# Make scrollable canvas expand based on the embedded frame

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating a frame which has many that are build vertically and I need a scrollbar to make them all visible. To do that I embedded my frame on a canvas.

The problem is that the widgets on the frame require more width that what the canvas provides as shown below

[image]

If I don't embed the frame on a canvas, then the widgets take the proper amount of width and are resized properly. I believe that the problem is the the canvas spans across 1 column whereas the widgets in the canvas require more than 2. I used `columnspan=2' on the canvas but the widgets on the embedded frame are still cut; they are just zoomed.

Is there a way to expand the width of the canvas according to the width they frame wants?

Here's an example code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

import os

# Method to make Label(Widget) invisible
def hide_frame(frame):
    # This will remove the widget
    frame.grid_remove()
    
# Method to make Label(widget) visible
def show_frame(frame, c, r):
    # This will recover the widget
    frame.grid(column=c, row=r)
    
    
def populate(frame):
    '''Put in some fake data'''
    for row in range(100):
        tk.Label(frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", 
                 relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
        t="Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah %s" %row
        tk.Label(frame, text=t).grid(row=row+4, column=1)
    
#____________________________________________________________________________________________   
#This will be the main window
window = tk.Tk()
#window.geometry('1500x1200')
window.attributes('-zoomed', True)
window.title("daq")

frame_main = Frame(window)
frame_main.place(rely=0.10, relx=0.0, relwidth=1.0)

#Create a tabcontrol
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(frame_main)
tabControl.grid(column=0, row=1)

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Digitizer tab
tab_Digitizer    = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab_Digitizer, text='   Digitizer   ')
digitizer_tab_dummy_label = Label(tab_Digitizer, text="")
digitizer_tab_dummy_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Channel settings

lbl_channel_registers = Label(tab_Digitizer, text="Channel registers", font='bold')
lbl_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)

frame_channel_registers = Frame(tab_Digitizer)
frame_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=4)

btn_hide_channel_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer, text="Hide", fg="red", command=lambda: hide_frame(frame_channel_registers) )
btn_hide_channel_registers.grid(column=1, row=3)


btn_show_channel_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer, text="Show", fg="green", command=lambda: show_frame(frame_channel_registers, 0, 4))
btn_show_channel_registers.grid(column=2, row=3)

##Channel settings - PSD

def onFrameConfigure(event):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    
def handle_user_scrolling(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(-event.delta/abs(event.delta)), "units")
    
def handle_scrollbar_scrolling(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))


lbl_PSD_channel_registers = Label(frame_channel_registers, text="DPP-PSD registers")
lbl_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=5, sticky=W)

btn_hide_PSD_channel_registers = Button(frame_channel_registers, text="Hide", fg="red", command=lambda: [hide_frame(canvas), hide_frame(myscrollbar)] )
btn_hide_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column=1, row=3)


btn_show_PSD_channel_registers = Button(frame_channel_registers, text="Show", fg="green", command=lambda: [show_frame(canvas, 0, 4), show_frame(myscrollbar, 1, 4)])
btn_show_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column=2, row=3)

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame_channel_registers, borderwidth=1, background="#FF0000")
frame_PSD_channel_registers = Frame(canvas, background="#0000FF")
frame_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=25, sticky=W)

frame_PSD_channel_registers.bind("<MouseWheel>", handle_user_scrolling)
frame_PSD_channel_registers.bind("<Configure>", handle_scrollbar_scrolling)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(frame_channel_registers ,orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
#canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

myscrollbar.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=NS)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=3)

#frame_PSD_channel_registers = Frame(canvas, background="#0000FF")
#frame_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=25, sticky=W)

#frame_PSD_channel_registers.bind("<MouseWheel>", handle_user_scrolling)
#frame_PSD_channel_registers.bind("<Configure>", handle_scrollbar_scrolling)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_PSD_channel_registers, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

###### PSD channels settings

#Short gate
def short_gate_width_selection(event):
    print ("Short gate width          : " + str( entry_short_gate_width.get() ) + " " + var_short_gate_width_unit.get() )
    pass
    
lbl_short_gate_width = Label(frame_PSD_channel_registers, text="Short gate width")
lbl_short_gate_width.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=25, sticky=W)

var_short_gate_width = IntVar(frame_PSD_channel_registers)
var_short_gate_width.set("15")

entry_short_gate_width = Entry(frame_PSD_channel_registers, width=10, textvariable=var_short_gate_width, exportselection=0)
entry_short_gate_width.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=W)

opt_short_gate_width      = ["samples", "ns"]
var_short_gate_width_unit = StringVar(frame_PSD_channel_registers)
var_short_gate_width_unit.set(opt_short_gate_width[0]) # default value
short_gate_width_unit     = OptionMenu(frame_PSD_channel_registers, var_short_gate_width_unit, *opt_short_gate_width, command = short_gate_width_selection)
entry_short_gate_width.bind('<Return>', short_gate_width_selection)
short_gate_width_unit.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=W)



#Long gate
def long_gate_width_selection(event):
    print ("Long gate width          : " + str( entry_long_gate_width.get() ) + " " + var_long_gate_width_unit.get() )
    pass
    
lbl_long_gate_width = Label(frame_PSD_channel_registers, text="Long gate width")
lbl_long_gate_width.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=25, sticky=W)

var_long_gate_width = IntVar(frame_PSD_channel_registers)
var_long_gate_width.set("100")

entry_long_gate_width = Entry(frame_PSD_channel_registers, width=10, textvariable=var_long_gate_width, exportselection=0)
entry_long_gate_width.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

opt_long_gate_width      = ["samples", "ns"]
var_long_gate_width_unit = StringVar(frame_PSD_channel_registers)
var_long_gate_width_unit.set(opt_long_gate_width[0]) # default value
long_gate_width_unit     = OptionMenu(frame_PSD_channel_registers, var_long_gate_width_unit, *opt_long_gate_width, command = long_gate_width_selection)
entry_long_gate_width.bind('<Return>', long_gate_width_selection)
long_gate_width_unit.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)



#Extras word options
def extras_word_options_selection(event):
    if 'Counter' in var_extras_word_options_selection.get():
        extras_word_options_step_counter.grid(column=2, row=22, sticky=W)
    else:
        extras_word_options_step_counter.grid_remove()
    print ("Extras word options       : " + var_extras_word_options_selection.get() )
    pass
    
def extras_word_options_step_counter_selection(event):
    print ("Step for trigger counter       : ", var_extras_word_options_step_counter.get() )
    pass
    
lbl_extras_word_options_selection = Label(frame_PSD_channel_registers, text="Extras word options")
lbl_extras_word_options_selection.grid(column=0, row=22, padx=25, sticky=W)

opt_extras_word_options_selection  = ["[31:16] = Extended Time Stamp   , [15:0]  = Baseline * 4",
                                      "[31:16] = Extended Time Stamp   , [15:0]  = Flags",
                                      "[31:16] = Extended Time Stamp   , [15:10] = Flags, [9:0] = Fine Time Stamp",
                                      "[31:16] = Lost Trigger Counter  , [15:0]  = Total Trigger Counter",
                                      "[31:16] = Positive Zero Crossing, [15:0]  = Negative Zero Crossing",
                                      "Fixed value = 0x12345678 (debug use only)."]
var_extras_word_options_selection = StringVar(frame_PSD_channel_registers)
var_extras_word_options_selection.set(opt_extras_word_options_selection[2]) # default value
extras_word_options_selection     = OptionMenu(frame_PSD_channel_registers, var_extras_word_options_selection, *opt_extras_word_options_selection, command = extras_word_options_selection)
extras_word_options_selection.grid(column=1, row=22, sticky=W)


#This keeps the window open - has to be at the end
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try changing the width of canvas as the same as the frame inside `onFrameConfigure()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for the comment! I don't think I'm using the function `onFrameConfigure()`; it just stuck there from several trials.

Comment: It should be inside `handle_scrollbar_scrolling()` instead of `onFrameConfigure()`.